# Why does AWS Lambda run multiple times via CloudWatch event?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

I have a lambda function build with python.
The lambda function executes a docker image which is hosted on AWS ECR.

The python code in the docker container:

- pulls data from rest api
- parses the data
- sends an event based on the parsed data via AWS SNS

When I trigger the AWS function via test it just gets executed once.
When I execute the code locally on my machine it also just gets executed once.

But when the lambda function gets triggered by a CloudWatch event (Cloudbridge) lets say every 5 minutes.
The code gets executed multiple times.

I tried the following:

- try using python sleep timer
- configure the timeout from aws lambda to 5 minutes
- deleting the function and pushing the docker image into ecr again
- writing the to be send events into a tmp/ file and read from it again

I use the docker image to not use with dependencies in lambda.

Comment: What do you mean that it exutes multiple times? Did you set its concurrency to 1 to force only one concurrent execution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aws lambda retry behavior when triggered by cloudwatch event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48707630/aws-lambda-retry-behavior-when-triggered-by-cloudwatch-event)

Comment: @shimo No. Set the Asynchronous invocation to 0.

Comment: @Marcin by multiple times I mean that I have a send sms statement as well as print statements which I can see in the logs as well as receiving 2 SMS when the function was executed